# BotDetect CAPTCHA not working in https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, https, captcha

I have added a captcha (BotDetect CAPTCHA) to my asp.net MVC form. But it is working correctly in the http site but not working in https.

I followed below documentation.

https://captcha.com/doc/aspnet/asp.net-mvc-captcha-quickstart.html

This is my http site.
[image]

But in https;

[image]

These are the errors i get in browser console.

```
/BotDetectCaptcha.ashx?get=script-include 404 (Not Found)
/BotDetectCaptcha.ashx?get=layout-stylesheet 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught ReferenceError: BotDetect is not defined
/BotDetectCaptcha.ashx?get=image&c=ExampleCaptcha&t=be41dfc9b19b449f98fdd794a00e1cfa 404 (Not Found)
/BotDetectCaptcha.ashx?get=reload-icon 404 (Not Found)
/BotDetectCaptcha.ashx?get=sound-icon 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I missed below in web.config (in Live).

```
<remove name="BotDetectCaptchaHandler" />
<add name="BotDetectCaptchaHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET" path="BotDetectCaptcha.ashx" type="BotDetect.Web.CaptchaHandler, BotDetect" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues that took way too long to resolve.  Adding the following to the handlers fixed the issue for me.

```
resourceType="Unspecified"
```

such as:

```
<add name="BotDetectCaptchaHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET" path="BotDetectCaptcha.ashx" type="BotDetect.Web.CaptchaHandler, BotDetect" resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

I found this at [Problem mapping HttpHandler --> HTTP Error 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858738/problem-mapping-httphandler-http-error-404-not-found)